# SQL Best Practice - UPDATE or calc within SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I got a flag when creating this post that it may be closed due to being subjective, so I hope I'm not breaking any rules here...but here goes:

I have a SQL query (SQL Server 2014) that does an Average Price calculation and was wondering which of the following is best practice.

Option 1:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
ItemCount INT
,ItemTotal MONEY
,AvgPrice MONEY
)

INSERT #Test
SELECT
COUNT(Item)
,SUM(ItemPrice)
,0
FROM [table]

UPDATE #Test
SET AvgPrice = ItemTotal/ItemCount
```

Option 2:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
ItemCount INT
,ItemTotal MONEY
,AvgPrice MONEY
)

INSERT #Test
SELECT
COUNT(Item)
,SUM(ItemPrice)
,CAST(SUM(ItemPrice) AS FLOAT)/CAST(COUNT(Item) AS FLOAT)
FROM [table]
```

With the  of data currently in `[table]`, these both run in the same amount of time and have the same results, but which of these would be better when `[table]` gets a lot bigger?

Comment: Your best bet is to try it and see your own results.  Depending on your client of choice write a loop and measure the time taken to run this 100,000 times or so.

Comment: First, don't use `money`, it has limited precision. Use decimal. Don't use `float` either because you *will* have unexpected rounding errors. Second, the UPDATE will perform roughly twice the I/O of the original insert (changing the data pages, writing to the log), why do it this way at all? Why not use `AVG` ? What is the schema of `table` ?

Comment: @mcr there's no need to try, INSERT + UPDATE means twice the work. In any case, clicking on 'Display Execution Plan' will show the performance difference in great detail

Comment: There's always reason to try for yourself, then you don't have to ask a group of people for a result you can figure out by yourself.  Then the question you can ask is a better one, ie "Why is approach A faster than approach B"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're absolutely right, using `AVG` is the best way to approach Option 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the 2nd one - because it does not require a second run through the table. This is once it is large enough for this to matter. Which may never be the case (difference at a million rows should be negligible).

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, your temporary table will have only one row in it (since you are inserting the result of aggregate functions without explicit grouping). The length of time required to update a table with a single row in it will normally be imperceptible - so both approaches are effectively likely to always take the same length of time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but would both methods still take the same length of time?  2 calculations in the `INSERT` then a quick `UPDATE`, or 3 calculations in the `INSERT`, assuming the data included in the calculations is 1 million rows or more?

Comment: *Effectively* the same length of time - I would expect approach 1 to take slightly longer (since you are performing the same calculations in both cases, but more file operations - insert, update - in the first scenario than in the second - insert only), but the difference would be so small as to be unnoticeable.